# Laravel:Method ...Controller::show does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to validate post request. I think when the validation fails, it gives me this error message.

app/Http/Controllers/InternationalShippingController.php

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //echo '<pre>';
    $post = $request->post();
    $order_ids = session('international_order_ids');
    //var_dump($order_ids);
    //var_dump($post);

    $validator = Validator::make(
      $post,[
          'documents.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf|max:5000|nullable',
          'company_name' => 'nullable',
          'shipping_address1' => 'nullable',
          'message' => 'size:1000',
        ],[
            'image_file.*.mimes' => __('Only jpeg,png and pdf files are allowed'),
            'image_file.*.max' => __('Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an document is 5MB'),
        ]
    );

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('internationalshippings/create2')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('internationalshippings/create2','InternationalShippingController@create2');
Route::resource('internationalshippings','InternationalShippingController');
```

I haven't made show() method in the controller.
Does this error mean when the validation fails, it tries to redirect to internationalshippings/show method?
When the validation fails,I'd like this to redirect back to internationalshippings/create2. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: to achieve this your have to define router manually. i seen you define with Route::resource. this resource method automatically  define route access controller method. see router list by php artisan route:list commend so you will understand which route accessing which method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the `resource` controller,
in `resources` this url `internationalshippings/SomeThing` means the `show` method i mean this url calls the `show` method in resource

**First way**
so you can use this in your fail return:
`return redirect()->route('your_route_name')` OR `return back()`

**Second way**
and the second way is in your web.php, when you are defining the resource route, type in this way:
`Route::resource('internationalshippings','InternationalShippingController',['except'=>['show']]);`

---

**EDIT**:
in your code situation the best way is change `Return`, because the url that you want to redirect to it, is `POST`

Comment: Thank you
I tried using 'back()' method, however it still gives me the same error.
I also tried 'redirect()->route('internationalshippings/create2')' but this time I get
'Route [internationalshippings/create2] not defined.' error.
Is this because it's trying to access this route via get method? How can I fix this?

Comment: @seitymo why `Route::post('internationalshippings/create2','InternationalShippingController@create2');` is `post` ???, usually the form that you're just getting the information for sending to controller is `GET` method not `post`, i can not understand why this route is `post` ???

Comment: It's only because the url will be very long. but I think you are right. I changed the route to 'get' and it's working now. Thank you!